# How to align combo box horizontal in extjs4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

Can anybody tell How to align combo box horizontal in extjs4.1

e.g

combo1  combo2   combo3

combo4 combo5    combo6

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Hbox` layout to achieve this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    items: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: 'hbox',
        defaults: {
            flex: 1
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'combobox'
        }, {
            xtype: 'combobox'
        }, {
            xtype: 'combobox'
        }]
    }, {
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: 'hbox',
        defaults: {
            flex: 1
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'combobox'
        }, {
            xtype: 'combobox'
        }, {
            xtype: 'combobox'
        }]
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/N0OxrdRJMnpBXMVsRs1p?p=preview